# Symfony2 translation issues since 2.6

Tags: symfony, twig

I was previously using Symfony 2.4.1 and recently upgraded to 2.6.*. I don't know if it's relevant to my problem but I just recently saw the problem and can't figure out why my text won't translate.

I am using the following syntax to translate my text:

```
{% trans from "checkout" %}Passer à la caisse{% endtrans %} // Should output Checkout
```

- The translation file is under "app/Resources/translations/checkout.en.yml" folder.
- If I output {{ app.request.locale }} it output "en".

While testing, I looked for an alternative method to output my translation :

```
{{ 'Passer à la caisse' | trans({}, "checkout", app.request.locale) }}
```

And... it works! Obviously I would like to solve my issue without refactoring my whole app.

Cheers.

EDIT: This is the content of my checkout.en.yml

```
Passer à la caisse : Checkout
```

EDIT 2 : Here's my config.yml

```
framework:
    translator:      { fallback: "fr" }
    default_locale:  "fr"
```

I have a Customer entity that tracks his session.

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
        // ...
        $request->setLocale($customer->getDefaultLocale()->getIsoCode());
        $request->setDefaultLocale($customer->getDefaultLocale()->getIsoCode());
        // ...
 }
```

Comment: What about `{% trans from "checkout" into app.request.locale %}`? Just want a test on one more variation.

Comment: @sjar Hughhhhhh it works... why?!! I should probably open an issue on github?

Comment: What if you change your `config.yml` to [have `framework: default_locale: en`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#setting-a-default-locale)? Take the `into app.request.locale` out of the `trans` tag.

Comment: @sjar Then it does the opposite. If the user select the "fr" locale it will output in english unless  I add the 'into app.request.locale'. I will update the question with a little more information about my config.

Comment: Last test, what if you set a locale in the controller before the render? `$this->get('request')->setLocale('en_US');`

Comment: @sjagr That's currently what I'm doing, I just updated the example with a snippet from my controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are among [a handful who are experiencing this problem](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/12878). [Here is a more recent issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/12988).

No one seems to be admitting whether this is desirable behaviour or an actual bug.

Your best solution is to exactly follow the guide for [configuring the "sticky locale" during a User's session](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/session/locale_sticky_session.html). People seem to be mentioning `17` as a good priority number in the linked issues and in the cookbook itself.

In your `services.yml` make sure you have something similar to:

```
acme.demo.event_listener.locale:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener\LocaleListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

And in the actual listener, a `getSubscribedEvents()` method with the priority defined:

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return array(
        // must be registered before the default Locale listener
        KernelEvents::REQUEST => array(array('onKernelRequest', 17)),
    );
}
```

Comment: I accepted this answer as the good one as it should fit most people need. In my special case my app is fairly complex and I elected to add "into app.request.locale" to fix my problem. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You have no qualifier for your translation string:

```
name_qualifier: Passer à la caisse
```

something like that should be in your translation yml file, then this should be all you need to get your translation:

```
{{ 'name_qualifier' | trans({}, "checkout") }}
```

**Update**

You can set a default domain for the hole template:

```
{% trans_default_domain "app" %}
```

Comment: I updated my answer with the content of checkout.en.yml. Your example will work but will not fix my issue. If I use this format, I will need to format my whole application and I obviously don't want this. I would like it to work using the trans block.